# Google SpreadSheet Query - Merge queries results into one

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, google-query-language

Let's take this data in a Google sheet:

```
| Product | Green | Red | Date      |
| A       | 1     | 0   | 1/1/2020  |
| A       | 1     | 0   | 2/1/2020  |
| B       | 0     | 1   | 2/25/2020 |
| C       | 1     | 0   | 2/28/2020 |
| A       | 0     | 1   | 3/1/2020  |
```

My goal would be to display the sum of Green / Red for each product:

- From the beginning of the year,
- For the current month.

I created this Google Query to get the results for all the year:

```
=QUERY(DATA!A:D,"select A, sum(B), sum(C) where D >= date '2020-01-01' and D <= date '2020-12-31' group by A")
```

I get this result:

```
| Product | sum Green | sum Red |
| A       | 2         | 1       |
| B       | 0         | 1       |
| C       | 1         | 0       |
```

And this query for the given month (I simplified the query, but I have a Settings sheet to specify the month to query):

```
=QUERY(DATA!A:D,"select A, sum(B), sum(C) where D >= date '2020-01-01' and D <= date '2020-01-31' group by A")
```

And get this result:

```
| Product | sum Green | sum Red |
| A       | 1         | 0       |
```

Now I'm stuck in joining the two results into one, like this:

```
| Product | Year sum Green | Year sum Red | Jan sum Green | Jan sum Red |
| A       | 2              | 1            | 1             | 0           |
| B       | 0              | 1            |               |             |       
| C       | 1              | 0            |               |             |
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, QUERY(DATA!A:D, 
 "select A,sum(B),sum(C) 
  where month(D)+1 = 1 
  group by A 
  label sum(B)'Jan sum Green',sum(C)'Jan sum Red'"), {2,3}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]